# Installation of camlimages with OPAM

Tags: ocaml, opam

I'm trying to install the module camlimages with opam. When I launch `opam install camlimages` in my shell, the compilation of camlimages failed and I have this message :

```
* pngwrite.c: In function ‘write_png_file_rgb’:


* pngwrite.c:65: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
* pngwrite.c: In function ‘write_png_file_index’:
* pngwrite.c:174: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
* *** omake: targets were not rebuilt because of errors:
*    src/pngwrite.o
*       depends on: src/pngwrite.c

'opam install camlimages' failed
```

If someone helps me, it's gonna be cool because I need this module for a project. 
I'm on Moutain Lion (version 10.8.2)

Comment: Do not use the tag “caml” for OCaml questions. CAML enthusiasts use it. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/caml/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has been a whole discussion on the caml-list, with in particular this message:

[Message on Caml-list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/fa.caml/E3ye-blN6Kg/discussion)

that gives a link to a repository containing camlimages that should compile on Mac OS X.

Comment: It's weird because I looked the website that you're given, the installation was a succes but when I execute an example for to check the module camlimages, I have the message "error Error: Unbound module Graphic_image".